# Sails.js model function returns undefined in view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

In my Sails.js app, I am trying return the number of approved users from my database and use the count variable in my view using the count() query. I have written below code to my Users.js model file:

```
countapproved: function(req, res) {
    Users.count({ approval_state: 'approved' }).exec(function(err, found) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error.');
        }
        console.log(found);
        return found;
    });
}
```

And, I am trying to get the value in my view with this EJS snippet:

```
<%= Users.countapproved() %>
```

The problem is that console.log(found); returns the correct value but in the view I am seeing 'undefined'.

edit: Users model is globally accessible.

edit2: I have no problem having this in my view /users/countapproved.ejs with res.view({ count: count }); but I am trying to access this from the homepage.ejs.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: What is the name of the controller?

Comment: model: Users.js
controller: UsersController.js

Comment: Change `Users.countapproved()` to `sails.controllers.Users.countapproved()`

Comment: hi, it says 'Cannot read property 'countapproved' of undefined'. By the way the function was originally placed in the model itself, I moved it to the controller like you suggested and made the change.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that your method was in model, can you try `sails.models.Users.countapproved()`

Comment: It gives the same error as above, I believe models are globally accessible in sails so sails.models would only work if that is disabled

Comment: Well yeah, that's why I thought that since your earlier code is not working let's try explicitly mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that `ejs` templating supports passing functions in out of the box. Googling for that certainly turns up a lot of tricky ways to do so.

However, before worrying about that, I don't think your `countapproved` method is doing what you want, because it has some asynchronicity issues. When it calls `Users.count().exec()`, it does so asynchronously. Before the callback of `exec` is run, the code continues below and, finding the end of the function, returns null. When the code in the callback is run, the function has already returned (although, the console.log runs just fine).

So, if I were you, I wouldn't mess around with trying to get my template to run a function, esp an asynchronous one. And I would update your `Users` method with a callback parameter:

```
countapproved: function(callback) {
    Users.count({ approval_state: 'approved' }).exec(function(err, found) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error:' + err);
        }
        console.log(found);
        callback(err, found);
    });
}
```

Then when you want the approval count in your view, you'll have to route through a controller method. In `/config/routes.js`:

```
'GET /someroute': 'SomeController.someMethod'
```

And in `/api/controllers/SomeController`:

```
module.exports = {

    someMethod: function(req, res) {
        Users.countapproved(function(err, found) {
            if (err) {
                // handle the error
            }
            return res.view('someView',{found: found});
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't get where should I put the second block of code. Should it be in the view? How can res.view understand its target view if it is in the view ittself?

Comment: The second block of code would go in a controller method that is used to return your view. Maybe you have been routing directly to views and haven't been using controller methods, so haven't seen this. I'll put those details in the answer.

Comment: I think I am not able to understand the concept here. I did not create a controller method as I don't want to access this inside a route called /users/controllername I want to access this inside homepage.ejs ('/'). But does it make sense to bind the GET '/' route to this method?

Comment: You can, yes. If you want special data to be present in your view, then my understanding is that that is what you *should* do. But test it out. Create a dummy view, and pass in some dummy data (like `res.view('dummyView', {testString: 'hello there'})` in a controller method). Once you get used to it, it's very powerful and versatile.